# Changing multiple background images on click with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I an trying to have multiple background image changes on click using javascript.

Can anyone help here I am trying to change multiple background images with a click, with this code I am getting 2 image changes but somewhere at the function updateIndex I can't work out how to make it continuous throughout multiple images.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <div id="body" class="imageOne"></div>
  <style>
    html,
    body, {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #body.imageOne {
      background-image: url("first.svg");
    }

    #body.imageTwo {
      background-image: url("2.svg");
    }

    #body.imageThree {
      background-image: url("3.svg");
    }

    #body.imageFour {
      background-image: url("first.svg");
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    var bodyObj, className, index;

    // all background images, calling them to change

    bodyObj = document.getElementById('body');
    index = 1;
    className = [
      'imageOne',
      'imageTwo',
      'imageThree',
      'imageFour',
    ];

    function updateIndex() {
      if (index === 0) {
        index = 1;
      } else {
        index = 1;
        index = 2;
      }
    }

    bodyObj.onclick = function(e) {
      e.currentTarget.className = className[index];
      updateIndex();
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Please take care to format your questions so they're readable. I've edited the question for you in this case

Answer (score 2):

Set the `index` to `0`
and in order to loop use `++index % className.length`

```js
const className = ['imageOne','imageTwo','imageThree','imageFour']; 
let index = 0;

function updateClassName() {
  this.className = className[++index % className.length];
}

document.getElementById('body').addEventListener("click", updateClassName);
```

```css
html, body{height: 100%;width: 100%; margin:0;}
#body{ height: calc(100% - 4rem); background: center / cover; }
#body.imageOne   {background-image: url("//placehold.co/800x600/0bf/fff");}
#body.imageTwo   {background-image: url("//placehold.co/800x600/f0b/fff");}
#body.imageThree {background-image: url("//placehold.co/800x600/b0f/fff");}
#body.imageFour  {background-image: url("//placehold.co/800x600/fb0/fff");}
```

```html
Click the image
<div id="body" class="imageOne"></div>
```

Comment: Nothing appears when running snippet. Could it be that address `//placehold.it` is invalid?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes, the images source died. Updated with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the logic in the `updateIndex()` function. You only set the `index` to `0`, or to `1`, then for some reason `2` immediately. It doesn't cycle around.

To fix the logic you can simply increment the `index` on each successive click. Try this:

```js
var bodyObj = document.getElementById('body'),
  index = 1,
  className = ['imageOne', 'imageTwo', 'imageThree', 'imageFour']; // remove trailing comma here

function updateIndex() {
  index = ++index % className.length;
}

bodyObj.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.currentTarget.className = className[index];
  updateIndex();
});
```

```css
#body {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
#body.imageOne { background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/250/000000/ffffff"); }
#body.imageTwo { background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/250/cc0000/000000"); }
#body.imageThree { background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/250/00cc00/000000"); }
#body.imageFour { background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/250/0000cc/000000"); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body" class="imageOne"></div>
```

Also note the use of `addEventListener()` over the outdated `onclick`.